# How to print formatted report for boolean and datetime.datetime type?

Tags: python

```
import datetime

date = datetime.datetime.now()
result = True
phoneNum ="(111)111-1111"
Message = "Hey !"
tmp = "{0:10s}{1:}{2:}{3:10s}".format(phoneNum, date,result, Message)
```

What format should I use for the datetime.datetime and boolean like we would use 's' for string and 'd' for integer
And how to make date format printed as Dec 3, 2016 8:00PM

Comment: Most classes implement a `__str__` method that represents the object as a string. For datetime you need to specify the date format separately. You should use `strftime` to print the time.

Answer (score 1):

I find it easiest to print this way, use curly braces with the index of the argument in the .format() method. No need to specify data type in the string, and if you only have 1 argument you don't need the numerical index.

For more information on the date formatting see this [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

```
import datetime

date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%b %d, %Y %I:%M%p')
result = True
phoneNum ="(111)111-1111"
Message = "Hey !"
tmp = "phone: {0}\ndate: {1}\nresult: {2}\nMessage: {3}".format(phoneNum, date, result, Message)

print(tmp)

variable = 'Variable printed without specifying an index'

print('\nstring: {}'.format(variable))
```

Output:

```
phone: (111)111-1111
date: Dec 6, 2016 07:00PM
result: True
Message: Hey !

string: Variable printed without specifying an index
```

Comment: I think you wanted to `%d` instead of `%w` for the day part of the date formatting. `%w` will give you the day of the week in numerical form

Comment: Correct, thank you lemonhead. I have made the change.